# Accessing a SQL Server Denali CTP1 database with Management Studio 2012 SP1 Express

Tags: sql-server-2012

I had Management Studio 2011 Denali CTP1 installed before but I have uninstalled it.

Now I have installed the Management Studio 2012 SP1 Express without any database instances.

I have a webserver with a few SQL server instances, one of them was installed by the Denali CTP1 installer. I'm able to connect to it wothout problems with a Denali CTP 1 SSMS but not with the 2012SP1.

When I connect with SSMS2012SP1 I immediately get the error:

> Invalid object name 'sys.database_filestream_options'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 208)

Although I'm connected to the database (and able to create or modify users for example), nearly every item throws some error when I expand it.

For example expanding "Databases" throws:

> Invalid column name 'synchronization_state'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 207)

"Some authorization problem" - I thought. But after creating a new user and setting every possible right to it and trying to logging in with it, there is no difference.

I'm not able to figure out the problem.

I can access the database through code just fine, here is my connectionstring:

```
server\web11;Initial Catalog=a_database;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

So I figured that this is something Management Studio does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to upgrade the database to the full version of SQL Server 2012.  I'm not surprised that the beta database engine doesn't work with the full release of the management tool.  There's no guarantee that beta and RTM products will work together.

Comment: It's not that easy actually. I have said that 'I have a webserver' but I don't actually own it, and I'm not in the liberty to freely reinstall the SQL server instances. Installing SQL Server 2012 will also require licences not yet owned, so actually downgrading the database seems more possible. Still I don't want to touch the sql server instance if that is possible.

Comment: @SoonDead: Soon there won't be a choice. https://sqlblog.org/2011/04/21/your-denali-installation-will-self-destruct-in-5-4-3-5

Comment: Yeah, there's that problem as well.  You're best bet will be to get a copy of the CTP1 bits from somewhere (god only knows where) and uninstall the RTM software from your machine and install the matching version's bits.

Comment: @JonSeigel yes we have run into that issue. Luckily we have managed to dig up an old installer of the CTP1, installed an other database instance and a management studio, attached the databases, scripted them out and created them back on an SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.